# Customized sorting in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I want to sort on a MongoDB collection on some key in ascending order, and need the records that don't have the key to come last. e.g.

```
db.coll.find({}, {key: 1}).sort({key: 1})
```

gives:

```
{_id: 1}
{_id: 2, key: 1}
{_id: 3, key: 2}
```

but should give following instead:

```
{_id: 2, key: 1}
{_id: 3, key: 2}
{_id: 1}
```

Is there a way to do this with MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately mongoDB "when comparing values of different BSON types, MongoDB uses the following comparison order, from lowest to highest:" [DOCS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

1. MinKey (internal type)
2. Null
3. Numbers (ints, longs, doubles)
4. Symbol,String
5. Object
6. Array
7. BinData
8. ObjectID
9. Boolean
10. Date, Timestamp
11. Regular Expression
12. MaxKey (internal type)

When mongo generates the index it will include a null for those documents which has not got the key.
You can do it with two queries, with using spare index for the first.

If you define a spare index on key field the sort will return only those which has value. This one will exclude the documents that has no key for it. [DOCS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#sparse-indexes)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. You will have to set "key" to the theoretically maximum value when you create the documents. Alternatively you can do two queries (one to get all where "key" exists sorted, and an optional other without the "key" set at all to complement your result set if needed). Usually the latter is not possible due to various business rule constraints.

Comment: +1 Although not being so proficient that I dare go as far as saying "not possible", I can't see any reasonable/efficient way to do this.

Comment: It certainly isn't possible with a single native query. It is of course possible if you have no other requirements other than the correct result such as the two query solution I mentioned. That said in most environments not being able to do it quickly is effectively the same as it not being possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be done using the aggregation framework but it would be rather painful.  You would have to replace the missing keys with a marker value that is higher than the valid keys (easy by using a key of a type that sorts after the type of key you have, unless the keys are regexes), then sort the collection, then strip out the marker values.

It would be more efficient to do it in two regular queries using `$exist`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem:
I need to sort by text containing numbers in it, and numbers should be displayed AFTER strings.
The only way we see for now is to create an indexed field where numbers are replaced with characters so they would be ranked after strings.